# Определение цикла for

Tags: c#

В пространстве имён `System.Activities.Statements` есть определение циклов: while(While.cs), dowhile(DoWhile.cs), foreach(ForEach.cs). https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/Statements/While.cs
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в этом пространстве имён нет определения цикла for, и где оно находится?

Comment: Покажите, как бы вы им воспользовались при его наличии.

Comment: Создайте свой, на базе foreach. Спрашивать - попробуйте спросить у самой microsoft, это ж ведь их баг.

Comment: @nick_n_a что сразу баг то. Может, это фича :D

Comment: @tym32167 согласен. Надо было написать их творение.